# Is there any way to sort file list in google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I have many files (images) in my drive account. I need to get the list of these in a particular order(sequence). Or I need to change the sequence of this. Is this possible with google-drive-api?

Answer (score -2):

Put it in an array. You can then sort the array however you need it.

Comment: Actually my idea is that these images can be sorted by the user and the sequence could be remembered in google_drive resources (if that is/was possible).. so that next time I get the same sequence back.  Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Suggestion : On a File Resource, please add a member called applicationMetaData which can be a string to be interpreted as json. This will be maintained by the application that manipulates these files. This will help the applications to use the files in whatever manner they find suitable to them.